# Какую команду написать чтобы у телеграмм бота сразу появились кнопки?

Tags: java, telegram-bot

Хотел бы, чтобы у моего бота появлялись сразу кнопки или когда написать любые сообщения, появлялись кнопки, которые есть у бота. Когда скидываю ссылку бота знакомым, кнопки сразу не появляются.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы не пришлось нажимать на иконку(кнопки бота) которую я отметил желтым цветом. То бишь, не все могут догадаться об этой иконке.

Comment: бот отправляет сообщение, в котором предлагает сделать выбор